# Access FindFirst/FindNext returns Operation is not supported in this type of object

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have this code:

```
Sub printPdfPagesTest(formName As String, fileName As String)
''print each record into a separate pdf file, named according to invoice number

    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim whereCondition As String
    Dim saveName As String

    Dim strtemp2 As Long
    strtemp2 = 2281821648

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(fileName)   ''can also pass SQL in as a String

    ''add msgbox: create a number for input invoiceNumber
    ''get value from invoiceNumber  = inputbox ("enter starting invoice num"...)
    ''get value from end invoiceNumber = inputbox("enter ending invoice num"...)
    ''get a start value for the starting location (findRecord) -----need to plan this step out.
    ''add an if statement in do while loop. if where condition is not the end invoice number, keep going

    rs.FindNext "[invoiceNumber]=" & strtemp2

    DoCmd.Close acForm, formName
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

What I want is to find the position of `strtemp2` invoice number in a table and use `moveNext` and `movePrevious` on the record to navigate around the table.

I keep getting the error message:

> Operation is not supported for this type of object.

This happens on this line:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(fileName)
```

I tried changing `rs` to:

```
Dim rs as Recordset
```

However it still gives me the same error.

Comment: What is the value of *fileName* when you encounter that error?

Comment: Actually seems you should first get an Overflow error at `strtemp2 = 25698539646` because 25698539646 exceeds the capacity of a Long Integer.

Comment: "set rs - currentdb..."  post your actual code please....  there's no way this code actually works.. (includes HansUp's comment)

Comment: I just updated the post, please look into it. The stremp2 is set in the table as Long Integer, so I put the actual number in the code. (it has been changed)

Comment: Something is still not right.  The maximum value a Long integer can accept is 2147483647.  (`2 ^ 31 -1 = 2147483647`)  But your value, 2281821648, exceeds that maximum by 134338001.  (`2281821648 - 2147483647 = 134338001`)  Therefore I can't understand how your code does not trigger error #6, *"Overflow"* at `strtemp2 = 2281821648`

Comment: yeah, it's confidential so I changed the number. You can just make a smaller number and test it.

Comment: What is the value of *fileName* when you encounter the operation not supported error?

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a RecordSet from a file name. First open the database, then the recordset.